# Самовызывающиеся функции в jQuery(function() {})

Tags: jquery, javascript

Может ли кто нибудь объяснить для чего нужны самовызывающиеся функции внутри jQuery(function() {})? Насколько я понимаю вообще они нужны для того, чтобы не засорять глобальный объект. Однако когда я пишу код таким образом:

```
jQuery(function() {
  console.log(document === this) // true
  var testVar = 123;
})
typeof testVar; //undefined
typeof document.testVar; //undefined
```

Моя переменная testVar нигде не появляется (имею ввиду что насколько я понимаю контекстом функции является объект document, но после задания преременной testVar и отрабатывания функции в объекте document не появляется новая переменная).

**Вопрос:** имеется ли в самовызывающихся функциях внутри jQuery(function() {}) какой нибудь смысл?

Comment: Да. Функция в js является scope'ом переменных. Таким образом, она нужна, чтобы объявлять локальные переменные.

Надеюсь, смысл локальных переменных очевиден?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю чтобы не вызывать конфликта имен в глобальном объекте?

Comment: вот пример:


    for (var i=0;i<100;i++) {
    (function(i){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    },100);
    })(i);}

попробуйте это сделать без замыкания.

Comment: @arzzzen, в том числе

Comment: Да, спасибо это ясно. Просто изучаю чужой код я встретил такую запись
$(document).ready(function(){
/* --------------------------------------------------------
  Components
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
  (function(){
    // здесь код вызова различных jQuery плагинов
  })()
})

И у меня возник вопрос для чего код вызова плагинов нужно было оборачивать в SEF функцию если можно было его написать без нее.

Comment: так оно может собрано из чего-то, и там все кусочки изолированы, поэтому так получилось, даже если нет конкретно в этом месте смысла так писать, оно не вредно. кстати, я рекомендую писать

      jQuery(function($) { /*....*/ });

это сделает и document.ready и $==jQuery

Comment: Иногда это используется просто для разбиения кода на логические части.

Comment: Функция в этом примере не вызывается, а объявляется и передается как объект. Дело не только в области видимости. Дело в том, что она может быть вызвана асинхронно (в данном случае будет вызвана, когда сработает событие document.onload). 

Собственно даже если эти переменные объявить в верхней области видимости.

`var testVar;
jQuery(function() {
  console.log(document === this) // true
  testVar = 123;
})
typeof testVar; //undefined
typeof document.testVar; //undefined`

Они все равно будут undefined. Потому как на момент срабатывания typeof функция еще не будет вызвана.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery(function() {}) или $(function(){}) функция сработает после загрузки DOM дерева. Обычно манипуляция с элементами DOM дерева делается после загрузки всей страницы. Этот код:

```
typeof testVar; //undefined
typeof document.testVar; //undefined
```

сработает раньше этого кода:

```
jQuery(function() {
  console.log(document === this) // true
  var testVar = 123;
})
```

Переменная `var testVar = 123;`будет видна только у функции которой она била объявлена, если сделать так `window.testVar = 123;` она будет доступна в глобальной области видимости.

Пример:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function () {
            console.log(document === this) // true

            window.testVar = 123;
            t()
        });

        var t = function () {
            console.log(typeof testVar); 
            console.log(document.testVar); 
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

> имеется ли в самовызывающихся функциях внутри `jQuery(function() {})` какой нибудь смысл?

Они ну никак не самовызывающиеся. Где ты скобки вызва нашёл?

Эти функции передаются в jQuery, который их вызывает, когда загрузится документ.

Comment: "для чего нужны самовызывающиеся функции **внутри** jQuery(function() {})?" - я ведь и не писал что сама передаваемая в jQuery функция самовызывающаяся.

Comment: @arzzzen, там нет ни одной самовызывающейся.

Comment: Если вы перечитаете мой вопрос и комментарии к нему я думаю вы поймете о чем шла речь. Ответ я уже получил.